# Interface builder changes do not reflect in runtime

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

After some months of not opening this project, when I opened it today, every new view I add to my ViewController's interface in the corresponding Storyboard is not reflected. For instance, changing a button background does not reflect in the app at runtime.

Also, adding new views and referencing them through a @IBOutlet doesn't work as well. I get a nil view reference on my `viewDidLoad`. Weirdly enough, all the views I had before, and am accessing on the viewDidLoad are not nil. Only the new views I add have this problem.

I have tried clearing the DerivedData folder and simulator caches but I ran out of stuff to try out. Anyone else having this issue?

To sum it all, every change I do on the interface builder now is to being applied to my view.

I am running Xcode 12.5.

**EDIT:** I tried adding a UILabel programmatically and it works. So, this is something that is wrong with how the storyboard creates the view reference in the ViewController. I still need help tho.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps an obvious thing that you've already tried, but did you try Product->Clean Build Folder in Xcode?

Comment: Yes. I tried that already... Like 10 times :D

Comment: Sometimes storyboards do get corrupted. You might have to start over with a new storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue after some hours. What led to this was that somehow, when I localized the storyboard in the past, XCode created one storyboard per language instead of just creating 2 .string files for each language. So this did the trick:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Problem solved! Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

One scenario in which that might happen is this:

1. You have multiple targets with different sets of storyboards for each target
2. You modify a storyboard that is not accessible in the current target that you build

Comment: I only have a target on my app. And the storyboard I mentioned in my post is included in my Target's Membership

Comment: And, as I said, some of my outlets are not nil. Only the outlets I'm adding now are.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the constraints? any of them are overlapped/ clipped or not defined any constraints at all? (In case of new Views and not the BG color)